# How to import a cell array data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data in a text file with the format like below. How shall I import the data into MATLAB? Thanks!

```
{(38.7948,1319,0.8571,119,0),(39.0693,138,0.0897,21,0),(40.7911,63,0.0409,7,0),(103.4512,19,0.0123,5,0),(-26.0424,223,1.0000,28,0)}
{(35.8689,110,0.5093,14,0),(47.7915,41,0.1898,7,0),(59.7489,53,0.2454,7,0),(71.7298,12,0.0556,3,0)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always helpful if you in your question explain what you have tried so far, what the desired result would be or how you inteend to use it. That way the person answering the question don't have to assume a lot of things.

Here I assume that you would like to import each line as a cell with a set of number arrays within.

To get matlab to evalutate the expression correct the parentheses in the brackets need to be replaced

```
{(1,2),(3,4)} 
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect

{[1,2],[3,4]}
ans = 
    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

To read the file you could use `fopen` and then `fgetl` to get each line. When the result from `fgetl` isn't a char, the end of the file (EOF) is reached.

```
% Open file
f = fopen('...path\to\file.txt','r');

C = {};
while true
    % Read each line
    fStr = fgetl(f);
    if ischar(fStr)
        % Replace parentheses and evaluate expresission
        C{end+1} = eval(regexprep(fStr,{'(',')'},{'[',']'}));
    else
        % End of file
        break
    end
end
fclose(f)
```

Perhaps you need to include some error checks if the data in your file should be formated incorrect. You could also check out other ways to read data, for exmple `fread` or `fscanf`

Comment: Many thanks! This is what I am looking for.